# How to get an uploaded file as request body in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

There's a lot of content available explaining how to handle file uploads in Laravel, but all I've seen focuses on retrieving a file uploaded from a form data request.

Is a form data request the only "canonical" way in Laravel to handle file uploads?

How could I handle uploading a single file sent as the request body?

To help illustrate my question, here's Postman's setup for this.

[Postman screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FAfW.png)

Note that the AWS S3 Rest API, and several other APIs, handle file uploads this way, with the file content as the request body, with no form data.

Thanks for any explanation.

Answer (score 2):

According To Your Screenshot, To Get File When Using Uplaod Binary Use:

```
$fileContent = $request->getContent();
```

To Save It In Specific Path:

```
file_put_contents("YOUR PATH", $request->getContent());
```